# How to do a logical or in CLIPS?

Tags: knowledge-management, clips

Updated code:
where to add the check for `?f<-(practice-is-on-off OFF)`

```
 (defrule no-practice "Rules for when practice cannot be held"

        (or ?f <- (practice (number-of-paddlers ?p&:(< ?p 6)))
            ?f <- (practice (number-of-coaches ?c&:(< ?c 1))))

        =>
        (modify ?f (practice-is-on-off OFF)))

    ;end
```

---

I am defining a template in CLIPS and I am using logical operator OR.
However, when I load the template, it is throwing an error saying

```
[TMPLTDEF1] Invalid slot or not defined in corresponding deftemplate practice.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::no-practice "Rules for when practice cannot be held"
   ?f <- (practice (or
```

Here's what I have:
Thanks in advance for any insight. Thanks

```
(deftemplate practice "structure of a practice"

    (slot number-of-paddlers (type NUMBER))
    (slot number-of-coaches (type NUMBER))
    (slot practice-is-on-off (type SYMBOL) (default ON))
    (slot practice-id (type NUMBER))

)


(defrule no-practice "Rules for when practice cannot be held"
    ?f <- (practice 
    (or
            (number-of-paddlers
                ?v_number-of-paddlers&:(
                    < ?v_number-of-paddlers 6))

            (number-of-coaches
                ?v_number-of-coaches&:(
                    < ?v_number-of-coaches 1))

    )
    )

    =>
        (modify ?f (practice-is-on-off OFF)
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are attempting to match a slot named "or" in the `practice` deftemplate and that slot does not exist.  Here are two alternate versions of the "no-practice" rule that will accomplish what you are trying to do.:

Version 1:

```
(defrule no-practice "Rules for when practice cannot be held"
    (or ?f <- (practice (practice-is-on-off ON)
                        (number-of-paddlers ?p&:(< ?p 6)))
        ?f <- (practice (practice-is-on-off ON)
                        (number-of-coaches ?c&:(< ?c 6))))
    =>
    (modify ?f (practice-is-on-off OFF)))
```

Note that the rule above may fire twice for a `practice` unless you also check that `practice-is-on-off` is "ON" in the CE's.

Version 2:

```
(defrule no-practice "Rules for when practice cannot be held"
    ?f <- (practice (practice-is-on-off ON)
                    (number-of-paddlers ?p) (number-of-coaches ?c))
    (test (or (< ?p 6) (< ?c 6)))
    =>
    (modify ?f (practice-is-on-off OFF)))
```

Comment: Thanks @bogatron. I like version 1. However, it is causing the rule to go into an infinite loop when I do that.  I am trying to put a check '?f <- (practice (practice-is-on-off ON))'....but I am getting lost in the syntax of it...can you have a combination of AND and OR logic in the same rule in CLIPS?  Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: unless you also check that practice-is-on-off is "ON" in the CE's.....what's a CE?  how can I do this...that's what I was asking about in the above question too; I guess I missed your note there. Thanks again @bogatron.

Comment: CE = "Conditional Element" - It is just one of the antecedents in the "if" part of the rule.  To check for ON/OFF you probably want to modify your `practice` matching statement to be like `(practice (number-of-paddlers ?p&:(< ?p 6)) (practice-is-on-off ON)`. I'll modify my answer to add this.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @bogatron. This works as it should, and I understand the logical OR syntax.

Comment: You are welcome.  One suggestion for future questions: If you edit your initial question, it is better to put additions below the original question so people who search the site and find your question can easily follow what is going on and can benefit from your question/answer.